# Number of Zeros of a Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help solving this problem.  I think it involves Rouche's Theorem but I am not sure.

Determine the number of zeros of the function in the upper half plane. $f(z)=z^4+3iz^2+z-2+i$

Comment: so $z=a+b*i$ right?

Comment: half upper plane  means that imaginary part  $y$ should be  positive,so in your case  $y=(3*z^2+1)$

Comment: here one problem is that  how can we determine  or how can we use  $i$ here?for example we may write $f(z)=z^4+i(3*z^2+1)+z-2$

Comment: may also this help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81254/number-of-zeros-of-a-complex-polynomial

Answer (score 0):

so in you case  we have

$f(z)=z^4+i(3*z^2+1)+z-2$

upper half plane as i said is that iamginary part  is positive,but  first let say  that we can conclude   we  may have two function  like first  $f(z)=z^4+z-2$ and $g(z)=i(3*z^2+1)$

or we  could  say  that we have tree function

$f(z)=z^4$

$f_1(z)=i(3*z^2+1)$

$f_2(z)=z-2$

if we  measure  this inside simple controur for example when    $|z|=1$  then  we may have

$|f(z)|=1$

$f_1(z)=4$

$|f_2(z)|=-1$

so we are taking positive and minimum right  because of this pdf file
http://fbhs.snnu.edu.cn/kcwz/all/dianzijiaoan/chn7/7.9.pdf

so it should be $1$

or in case of two function  if we concatenate   first  two function we will get  $5$,so i think it should be for two function $5$

Comment: so please if something is incorrect,tell me and i will update,i  want just to help him